# Create WPF application that plays a browser game

Tags: .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

Hi :) I'd like to create a WPF application that can play a browser game on it's own (https://slowotok.pl/). How can I go about it? I'm very new to all .NET stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control for this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Source="https://slowotok.pl/" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: This allows me to display a game inside application - but will it allow me to create a code that actually plays the game on its own?

Comment: @Jecke you can look into the DOM of that embedded browser and make the clicks and such that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a WPF to do this. Try Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/ or create a browser extension.

Comment: I probably don't need to; but unfortunately I have to.